# Looks like my answer just disappeared, not even shown as a deleted one

Tags: support, bug

I do remember answering this particular question recently - and just saw it in a list as the one that has no answers - and I can not see my answer even as a deleted one. The link is [Security question regareding Tor & Anonsurf](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/22673/security-question-regareding-tor-anonsurf)

Comment: Since you have more than [a privilege to see deleted posts](https://tor.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), you can search your own deleted posts with `user:me deleted:1`. I had a guess that the same Q&A was asked and deleted after answered, then reposted as a new question... or [you answered a different question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/22684/6656).

Comment: That's the point! Usually I can see all the deleted stuff, but I **can't** see my answer even as a deleted one!

Comment: Usually, deleted posts that cannot be seen even by mods are those that have been deleted as spam or as offensive.  However, in this case you would have had the -100 reputation penalty.  This is unlikely to be the reason in your case and I would not accuse you of such a post.

Comment: I have no penalties, and the post was actually a technical answer - and I can't find it **anywhere**!